# Как правильно работать с load()

Tags: jquery, loading

На сайте создал простое модальное окно, теперь мне нужно загружать туда html файлы. У меня что-то не так идет. Посмотрите пожалуйста пример.

Например, при нажатии на ссылку:

```
<a href="page.html" id="button">Ссылка</a>
```

файл page.html должен загрузится в div class="**div2**":

```
<div id="div1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="div2">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Сам написал код такого вида:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.div2').load(this.href, function() {
        $('#div1').show();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Результат: div1 появляется, но page.html не загружается в div2.

Пример в [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NcPad/)

Не понимаю в чем моя ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: всё работает

http://plnkr.co/edit/45QlQu9EeGltyBs5ymEq?p=preview

Comment: @eicto, Благодарю за ответ. Я понял свою ошибку. Я работал локально :(